# Can't login with SSO - NOSTATE SimpleSaml (ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2)

Tags: .net-core-3.1, simplesamlphp, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have following problem:

I configured my .NET Core 3.1 app to be my service provider (according to [this](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp) tutorial, just changed identity provider - with Okta IdP mentioned in this guide everything works perfect) and actually I can go to my login page, which is Identity Provider in PHP (SimpleSAML). After login I have *SimpleSAML_Error_NoState: NOSTATE* and I stay logged out in my .NET app, but it seems that my login was sucessful, because I don't have to login on another sites which uses this IdP. Also upon going to login page in my app I don't have login page, but only this error. My cookies are set properly I believe, that is why I'm logged in on another app.

I don't know if I should post code fragments here, because it is the same as tutorial mentioned above, the only difference is appsettings.json.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the SimpleSAML_Error_NoState error is related to SimpleSAML. Maybe you can see more details in the SimpleSAML log.

Maybe SimpleSAML require an additional request parameter, but it is not anything I know about.